# My MouseInteractorStyle : undefined reference to `vtkInteractorStyleZoom ::New()'

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, vtk

i am on a vtk project
I wanted to write my own mouse interactor style
i writed this class

vtkInteractorStyleZoom.h

```
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera.h>

class vtkInteractorStyleZoom: public vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera
{
public:
  static vtkInteractorStyleZoom* New();
  vtkTypeMacro(vtkInteractorStyleZoom , vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera);

  virtual void OnLeftButtonDown();

};
```

vtkInteractorStyleZoom.cpp

```
#include "vtkInteractorStyleZoom.h"


vtkStandardNewMacro(vtkInteractorStyleZoom);

void vtkInteractorStyleZoom::OnLeftButtonDown()
{
    this->StartDolly();
}
```

and this the functions where i use this class

```
void ReadDICOMSeriesQt::on_ZoomButton_clicked()
{
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkInteractorStyleZoom> Style = 
vtkSmartPointer<vtkInteractorStyleZoom>::New();
    ui->qvtkWidget->GetRenderWindow()->GetInteractor()-
>SetInteractorStyle(Style);
}
```

and when i compiled my project with cmake i had a this problem

CMakeFiles\ReadDICOMSeriesQt.dir/objects.a(ReadDICOMSeriesQt.cxx.obj): In function `ZN15vtkSmartPointerI22vtkInteractorStyleZoomE3NewEv':
C:/VTK/VTK-7.0.0/Common/Core/vtkSmartPointer.h:117: undefined reference to`vtkInteractorStyleZoom::New()'

i dont know if there is any problem with cmake (maybe i must change somethings in my CMakeLists.txt)

is there anyone who can help me ?

Comment: The question title and the error message you show doesn't match.

Comment: it's the same error , i just make a mistake and i copied the error of an other class, a moment and  i edit my question

Comment: Shouldn't `vtkSmartPointer<vtkInteractorStyleZoom> Style = vtkSmartPointer<vtkInteractorStyleZoom>::New();` be `vtkSmartPointer<vtkInteractorStyleZoom> Style = new vtkSmartPointer<vtkInteractorStyleZoom>();`

Comment: i did this but i had this error
error: conversion from 'vtkSmartPointer<vtkInteractorStyleZoom>*' to non-scalar type 'vtkSmartPointer<vtkInteractorStyleZoom>' requested

Comment: Try to `#include <vtkObjectFactory.h>` where the vtkStandardNewMacro() is defined.

Comment: yes i included it and its work thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is the constructor definition. The constructor must take no arguments, so that the object factory mechanism works. Make it private, because noone should call it directly. 
You should also disable copy semantic of your class. I.e.

```
class vtkInteractorStyleZoom : public vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera
{
  public:
    static vtkInteractorStyleZoom* New();
    vtkTypeMacro(vtkInteractorStyleZoom, vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera);

    virtual void OnLeftButtonDown();

 private:
   vtkInteractorStyleZoom() { /* definition, if any */ }

   vtkInteractorStyleZoom(const vtkInteractorStyleZoom&) = delete;
   void operator =(const vtkInteractorStyleZoom&) = delete;
};
```

Also, you should `#include <vtkObjectFactory.h>` in the .cpp file -- that's where vtkStandardNewMacro() is defined.

Then make sure that the caller module (ReadDICOMSeriesQt) links against the library which vtkInteractorStyleZoom is part of.

Comment: i just included <vtkObjectFactory.h> and its work ! the constructor is herited from vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera